# How to autogrow a textarea element in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to have an textarea element that dynamically adjusts its height to the content of the textarea element.

How could I implement this in Dart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just using pure dart:html:

```
var textArea = querySelector('textarea');
textArea.onInput.listen((_) {
  // shrink the textarea when needed
  textArea.style.height = 'auto';

  // set the height to scrollHeight plus some correction
  var correction = textArea.offsetHeight - textArea.clientHeight;
  textArea.style.height = '${textArea.scrollHeight - correction}px';
});
```

You could also make an angular2 directive:

```
@Directive(
    selector: 'textarea[autogrow]',
    host: const {
      '(input)': 'onInput(\$event.target)'
    }
)
class AutogrowDirective {

  onInput(TextAreaElement textArea) {
    // shrink the textarea when needed
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';

    // set the height to scrollHeight plus some correction
    var correction = textArea.offsetHeight - textArea.clientHeight;
    textArea.style.height = '${textArea.scrollHeight - correction}px';
  }
}
```